# How to start a triangulation on a set of (boundary) points

Tags: computational-geometry, triangulation, delaunay, tessellation

I have a set of (boundary) points and I want to start triangulating them. From all references that I found, the authors only mentioned methods on how to add new points and hence create new edges (at the same time remove the old, bad points/edges), assuming that the points have been triangulated initially. So, how do I do the FIRST triangulation before I can use all the suggested methods (to add new points and edges) in the literature. For a simple case, say, if I have a circle with boundary points (x,y)=(r cos\theta,r sin\theta), I could possibly create a triangle for every three neighboring points. But then, there will be no edge crossing the region near the center of the circle.

Comment: What do you call *boundary points*, precisely ?

Comment: Thanks. They are the points that lie on the boundary of the domain that I want to discretize/mesh. @YvesDaoust

Comment: So they are just… points ? Are they ordered ?

Comment: They are not necessarily ordered. @YvesDaoust

Comment: Can the boundary be concave ?

Comment: I think it is a general shape of a boundary in two dimensions. The boundary can be concave or convex. I could quickly get (Delaunay) triangulation by using package (in matlab or python). But now, I would like to code it myself. Thanks. @YvesDaoust

Comment: So how do you obtain the boundary polygon ?